# My if and else coding doesn't work

Tags: java

First of all, I am new to this website and coding so please forgive my rookie mistakes, second of all my problem is, I intended to make a quiz via eclipse software using java coding (obviously). But everytime i run it, even when i type in the right answer it reacts like i typed in the wrong answer. Could you please point out my mistake?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Quiz {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Hi! Welcome to the Quiz! Please insert your username.");
    String userName = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Welcome " + userName + "! Let's start! Your first question is what is the capital of Norway?");
    String answer = in.nextLine();
    if (answer == ("Oslo"))
    System.out.println("Good Job! Your next question is how many states are there in U.S.A.?");

else        
{
    System.out.println("You've failed!");
}
    {

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    String answer1 = in.nextLine();
    if (answer1 == ("50"))
    System.out.println("Well done! Your next question is where did the first football world cup happen?");
    else        
    {
        System.out.println("You've failed!");
    }
    String answer2 = in.nextLine();
    if (answer2 == ("Uruguay"))
    System.out.println("Well done! Your next question is");
    else        
    {
        System.out.println("You've failed!");
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Also I would like to learn how to create a loop in my coding. For example after giving the wrong answer i want it to restart autumatically from question 1. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think Eclipse has anything to do with your question. It appears that's just the IDE you happen to be using.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [tour], go through the [help], read [ask] to know how this site works. Also read how to indent your code correctly as is, is near to impossible to understand what's happening. Read the linked /duplicate question to learn what's wrong. To restart, read about `do-while`.

Comment: Just use string.equals(otherString) to compare two strings.

Comment: I assume that it is off-topic for stackoverflow, as it is a request for debbuging help. Check this on how to debug in eclipse https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-debug-launch.htm

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with comparing strings.

Your situation should be solved when you change your if condition to:

```
 if (answer.equals("Oslo")) { // Do something }
```

When using equals() you compare the contents of what you try to compare. 
If you use == it actually compares the references of what you try to compare. Thus where the object is stored (answer) to the given string "Oslo", which is not equal and therefore returns false.

**In addition to your question in the comments**

To get a quick solution you can use nested if-else statements.

You can also use a new if statement for each question, just below each other. This would require a bit more rewriting of your code. See the example:

```
public class App {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hi! Welcome to the Quiz! Please insert your username.");
        String userName = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Welcome " + userName + "! Let's start! Your first question is what is the capital of Norway?");
        String answer = in.nextLine();
        if (!answer.equals("Oslo")) {
            System.out.println("You've failed!");
        }

        System.out.println("Good Job! Your next question is how many states are there in U.S.A.?");
        answer = in.nextLine();
        if (!answer.equals("50")) {
            System.out.println("You've failed!");
        }
        System.out.println("Well done! Your next question is where did the first football world cup happen?");
    }
}
```

However, as you can see code becomes pretty repetitive, so making use of function would be a good next step. See the next example:

```
public class AppWithFunction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hi! Welcome to the Quiz! Please insert your username.");
        String userName = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Welcome " + userName + "! Let's start!");

        handleQuestion(in, "Your first question is what is the capital of Norway?", "Oslo");
        handleQuestion(in, "Your next question is how many states are there in U.S.A.?", "50");
}

private static void handleQuestion(Scanner in, String questions, String answer) {
    System.out.println(questions);
         if (!in.nextLine().equals(answer)) {
            System.out.println("You've failed!");
        }
    }
}
```

It might be a bit out of your scope for the moment, but if you would have a bunch of questions, storing these in a map (question = key, answer = value), iterate over them and handle them accordingly would be a good next step.(Maybe a nice self-assigned new exercise later on;)).

Comment: if (answer.equals("Oslo")) {// System.out.println("Good Job! Your next question is how many states are there in U.S.A.?");
 }
 
 else  
 {
  System.out.println("You've failed!");
 }  i still couldn't manage to get it right. what did i do wrong? can you please write a working example for me? Thanks in advance @Crittje !

Comment: Gave you more details in the answer section :).